# ENV in Electron. Is It Possible?

Tags: reactjs, electron, environment-variables, electron-builder

I am having a React-Electron app. In the registration page, the user should type in an "Admin ID", which if correct, he/she can continue. So, the "Admin ID" should be hidden from the code. Therefore I used `dotenv` for accessing the `env` from `.env` file in development. For building the app I'm using `electron-builder` in Github Actions. So, how can I access the `env` in the production-ready app? Below is the `build.yml` for github actions:

```
name: Build
on: push

jobs:
  build_on_win:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'skip-publish')"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14"
          cache: "yarn"
      - name: install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: build react
        run: $env:CI=$false; yarn run build;
      - name: publish app
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: yarn run electron-ship
```

`scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"devstart": "electron .",
"electron-ship": "electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js build --win --publish always"
},
```

Thank you!